# How can I raise Keyboard events programmatically in my iOS application

Tags: ios, keyboard, keyevent

I am working on Remote desktop project for iPad. I am struggling with how to raise keyboard keyevents programmatically.(Shift,Control,Command,etc) keys  and how can I assign these keys to UIButton. which is designed in my ipad View. I have found the way in macOS but I didn't find in iOS. Is there any API's or Methods or Protocols to raise the keyboard events programmatically.

How can I come out with this problem?

Comment: What?  Over half of those commands don't exist on iOS.  Are you referring to an external keyboard?

Comment: If he's talking about remote desktop, I would guess that what he really wants is to send the signal corresponding to those key presses from the iPad to the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Enumerate the child windows of the current view controller's main view and when you find one that accepts text input, e.g. a UITextView or UITextField, call becomesFirstResponder on it`

```
for (UIView *view in myViewController.view.subviews)
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextView  class]]
    ||  [view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
    {
        [view becomeFirstResponder];
        break;
    }
}
```

for the opposite case, to dismiss the keyboard, just call `[myController.view endEditing];`